# How to run a substitute command with bufdo?

Tags: vim, neovim

I searched the docs for a bit, but cannot seem to find a satisfying answer.

Basically I want to insert a new line at the end of every buffer and fill this line
with the modified filename of the open buffer.

Example :

```
SomeText
\<old_eof\>
```

becomes

```
Some text
result of substitute(expand("%t"), "txt", "csv", "") and some wrapping text
\<new_eof\>
```

I already tried it with

`:bufdo normal Go<C-R>=substitute(expand("%t"), "txt", "csv", "")`

However, this solely outputs `<C-R>=substitute(expand("%t"), "txt", "csv", "")`

## EDIT:

I found a *partial* solution by simply recording a macro and using
`:bufdo normal @a`
However, this is not my desired way to go.

Comment: Your parentheses are off. I believe it should be: `substitute(expand("%:t"), ...)`. Does it work without `:bufdo`?

Comment: yeah sorry. Thanks's for noticing! That's a typo in my question. Did it correctly in vim and corrected it here now, too. It works neither with nor without bufdo.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the question's title so it does not reflect your attempted  solution. Feel free to [edit] and change it to something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you do that `<C-R>`? Do you press `<`, `C`, `-`, `R`, and `>` separately? Do you press `Ctrl+R`?

Anyway, using a normal mode macro doesn't sound like a good way to do what you want. `:help :put` would be more appropriate:

```
:bufdo $put=substitute(expand('%'), 'txt', 'csv', '')
```

where `$` is the address of the last line.

Note that I replaced the double quotes with single quotes because, well… let's say that `:put` has its idiosyncrasies. I also removed the seemingly useless `t` in `%t` (or did you mean `%:t`?).

--- EDIT ---

This can be improved substantially by using `:help filename-modifiers`:

```
:bufdo $put=expand('%:s/txt/csv/')
```

or, if you meant `%:t`:

```
:bufdo $put=expand('%:t:s/txt/csv/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a command through `:execute` like this:

```
:bufdo execute 'normal Go'..substitute(expand('%:t'),'txt','csv','')
```

Not the most elegant way* to do it but it worked for me.

See [`:help execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) for an explanation of both the command and the use of the `..` operator to concatenate strings.

---

*) While I'm typing this answer, romainl came up with a more beautiful solution. Now that I've typed those few lines I might as well post them...

Comment: Also good. But I like the solution using put better. :-P For whatever reason I did not think of put myself...

Comment: It's no secret romainl's answer is better. I said so myself and upvoted it. Faced with the decision to throw my answer away or post it, I decided to dump it on SO. Maybe somebody will find it useful - if only as an anti-pattern :-)

Comment: Not an anti-pattern, IMO. More like a fallback for when other methods get too complicated or fail. Even my solution could probably be improved via a smarter use of `:help filename-modifiers`.

Comment: FWIW, I did just that.

Comment: @romainl thank you for your kind words. I noticed your improved answer. Looks minimal, clean and nice. Reminds me a bit of Bash's variable expansion which can save you several lines of conditionals and `sed`.